# Equivalent LINQ to SQL query

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can anyone help me with the equivalent LINQ query for the SQL below?
I am new to LINQ

```
Select * From Students_History SH
Where SH.Active = 1 and SH.ModifiedAt in (
select MAX(SH1.ModifiedAt)from Students_History SH1
group by SH1.StudentId)
```

This is what I have tried

```
var q = 
    from h in Students_History
    where h.Active=1
    group h by h.StudentId into g
    select new 
    {
        StudentID = g.Key,
        LatestModified = g.Max (x => x.ModifiedAt)
    }
```

This linq query does not give me the right result and somehow the active=1  is ignored

I have about dozen fields in my Students_History table and I want all those fields not just studentId and ModifiedAt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var q =
    from hg in Students_History
    group hg by hg.StudentId into g
    join h in Students_History on g.Key equals h.StudentId
    where h.Active == 1 && h.ModifiedAt == g.Max(x => x.ModifiedAt)
    select new
    {
        StudentID = h.StudentId,
        LatestModified = h.ModifiedAt
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare using the **`==`** operator.

Comment: Well Active=1 is not the only problem. I am looking for the right query too.